Table of contents are overflowing out of the page
I have created separate files for my chapters and I use \include(chapter) command, but the table of contents are being overflowing out of my page and new page is not being created automatically. I have attached the code of my main file:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,xspace}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large\sffamily\scshape\color{blue}}
\ChNumVar{\Large\selectfont\color{blue}}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sffamily\color{blue}}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=BlueGreen}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\dottedcontents{chapter}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{section}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}
\dottedcontents{subsection}[oem]{}{3.3em}{1pc}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftaftertoctitle{\hfill\mbox{}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[theorem]{Exercise}
\newtheorem{notation}[theorem]{Notation}
\newtheorem*{notation*}{Notation}
\newtheorem*{definition*}{Definition}
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
%=======================================================================================================%
%========================================DECLARATION====================================================%
%=======================================================================================================%
\vspace*{3cm}
    \begin{center}
        \color{teal}\textbf{\LARGE DECLARATION}
    \end{center}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Declaration}
    \vspace{2cm}
    
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    [![SS of TOC][1]][1]
%==============================================================================================================%
%=========================================PREFACE==============================================================%
%==============================================================================================================%        
        \chapter*{\LARGE Preface}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
        Semigroup theory, as an independent branch of algebra, is a relatively young but rapidly growing area of mathematics. Since its formation approximately six decades ago, the field has become a dynamic subject of study with its own distinct objects, methods, and problems. A key component of semigroup theory is the study of transformation semigroups, which naturally arise in various mathematical contexts due to their inherent structure. Specifically, the composition of transformations, which is always associative, forms a semigroup when the set of transformations is closed under composition.
        
        Among the most prominent examples in transformation semigroups are the full symmetric semigroup, the symmetric inverse semigroup, and the partial transformation semigroup. These classical structures serve as foundational models in the study of finite transformation semigroups and provide a natural framework for many semigroup-theoretical investigations.
        
        Over the decades, significant work has been devoted to understanding these and related semigroups, including their algebraic properties, combinatorial aspects, and connections to other branches of mathematics. Despite the extensive progress made in the study of transformation semigroups, certain areas remain less explored, and research continues to uncover new insights and applications. Particularly within the context of finite semigroups, various structural properties and classifications have been subject to ongoing research.
        
        This dissertation focuses on the study of the semigroup , a specific class of transformation semigroups that has attracted considerable attention. Through a detailed investigation, it seeks to contribute to the understanding of the algebraic and combinatorial properties of this semigroup. Key aspects such as generating systems, rank properties, and semigroup presentations are examined, with particular emphasis on finite cases. The work presented here aims to add to the growing body of knowledge in the field of transformation semigroups, offering new results and perspectives that can serve as a foundation for further exploration.
        \hfill \hfill \clearpage \thispagestyle{empty}  \hfill 
    
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[CO]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\rightmark}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\hrule \vspace{0.15cm} Ranks and Presentations for Finite Transformation semigroups}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \include{Chapters/chapter1}
    
    \include{Chapters/chapter2}
    
    \include{Chapters/chapter3}
    
    \include{Chapters/chapter4}
    
    \include{bibliography}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
    
\end{document}


Note that you can click on the {} button to format code. You can also add three backticks (`)  in a separate line before and after the code block.

Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "overflowing out of the page". If I compile the above code, I don't get any warnings about overfull boxes, so everything is typeset as expected. There is [![SS of TOC][1]][1] in your code though which is probably a remnant of trying to add an image to your post. Maybe you can clarify the issue?

This seems to be caused by the titletoc package, in particular the command
\dottedcontents{chapter}[0em]{\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}

This seems to suppress a page break inside the ToC. This might be a bug in titletoc.
It appears to be cured by inserting a \pagebreak:
\dottedcontents{chapter}[0em]{\pagebreak[1]\bfseries}{2.9em}{1pc}


Erh, tocloft does not define \dottedcontents, it comes from titletoc

Sorry, my bad. Indeed it should have been titletoc.
